# Adding space between number and text using sed

Tags: sed

I want to add space between number and text using sed command as: 16a will be 16 a and 89jas will be 89 jas.

please let me know the answer

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to think about it:

```
echo "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" | \
 sed -r 's/([0-9])([a-zA-Z])/\1 \2/g; s/([a-zA-Z])([0-9])/\1 \2/g'
```

- add a whitespace between a digit-letter string & letter-digit string
- `()` is to capture the group and `\1` and `\2` is to return the first and
  second captured group

Comment: Very good.  To be unicode-safe, `[0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z]` should be replaced with `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:alpha:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/& /g'
```

or with a sed that supports EREs when invoked with -E, e.g. GNU sed and OSX sed:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/& /g'
```